# Android update UI on either gesture or after 5 seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, timer, android-handler

I am a newbie to Android. I want to update a UI (GestureOverlayView) on either receiving a gesture or after 5 seconds.
I am using-

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    updateMyScreen();
}
```

and this works great to update the screen but I want another thread which keeps tab of time (and after 5000 milliseconds) will trigger this update if the user does not put in a gesture.
Do I need to use Handler? I don't know how to approach this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 5000ms timer by many ways, but one of them is to create a **Handler** and post a **Runnable** to it as a delayed event like in the following code:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!updated) {
            updateMyScreen();
        }
    }
 }, 5000);
```

then you can define a boolean updated to keep state wether the screen has already been updated or not

```
boolean updated;
```

then in **onGesturePerformed** add similar check

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    if(!updated) {
        updateMyScreen();
    }
}
```

and finally in **updateMyScreen** method set updated to true;

```
void updateMyScreen() {
    //..
    updated = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't necessary use handler, you may use any view to post `Runnable`. 
I will give you an idea, but you have to add conditions whether to update screen after 5 sec elapsed etc:

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        updateMyScreen();

        overlay.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   updateMyScreen();
                }
            }, 5000);
    }
```

In this little example you update your screen twice - just when gesture is performed and after 5sec. Other logic is up to you:)

Comment: Here the delay is performed after the gesture, when the purpose was to update screen only after 5 seconds is passed **OR** after gesture being performed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*add your code here which code refresh every 5 seconds*/
            }
        }, 5000);
```